# What happend to InMemoryTransportCache in masstransit?

Tags: .net-core, masstransit

What happened to InMemoryTransportCache in masstransit and is there any option right now to test connection between two busControls in memory?

Answer (score 2):

You want to test as there were 2 different hosts that communicates over the bus in memory, right?

You could let the services share the same IBusControl instance and register each consumer by using the "ConnectRecieveEndpoint" method.

A short example to illustrate the usage of "ConnectReceiveEndpoint":

```
public class TestMessage { public string Text { get; set; } }

[Test]
public async Task Can_publish_and_receive_message()
{
    var consumer1Semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0);
    var consumer2Semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0);

    IInMemoryHost host = null; 

    var busControl = MassTransit.Bus.Factory.CreateUsingInMemory(inMemoryBusFactoryConfigurator =>
    {
        host = inMemoryBusFactoryConfigurator.Host; 

        inMemoryBusFactoryConfigurator.ReceiveEndpoint("consumer1", ep =>
        {   
            ep.Handler<TestMessage>(context =>
            {
                context.Message.Text.Should().Be("Hi");
                consumer1Semaphore.Release();
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });
        });
    });

    host.ConnectReceiveEndpoint("consumer2", inMemoryReceiveEndpointConfigurator =>
    {
        inMemoryReceiveEndpointConfigurator.Handler<TestMessage>(context =>
        {
            context.Message.Text.Should().Be("Hi");
            consumer2Semaphore.Release();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });

    });

    await busControl.StartAsync();

    await busControl.Publish(new TestMessage{Text = "Hi"});

    (await consumer1Semaphore.WaitAsync(2.Seconds())).Should().BeTrue();
    (await consumer2Semaphore.WaitAsync(2.Seconds())).Should().BeTrue();

    await busControl.StopAsync();
}
```

A simple approach to test 2 imaginary services; ServiceA and ServiceB (not co-hosted in a real environment). The IBusControlFactory below is used to be able to swap out Azure Service Bus transport in favor for the In Memory transport in tests.

```
public interface IBusControlFactory
{
    IBusControl Create(string queueName = null, Action<IReceiveEndpointConfigurator> configurator = null);
}

// Test replacement for a factory that normally creates a Azure Service Bus bus instance
public class Harness : IBusControlFactory, IDisposable
{
    public readonly IBusControl BusControl;

    private IInMemoryHost _host;

    public Harness() => BusControl = MassTransit.Bus.Factory.CreateUsingInMemory(configure: cfg => _host = cfg.Host);

    public static Harness Start() => new Harness();

    public IBusControl Create(string queueName = null, Action<IReceiveEndpointConfigurator> configurator = null)
    {
        if(queueName != null && configurator != null)
            _host.ConnectReceiveEndpoint(queueName, configurator);

        return BusControl;
    }

    public void Dispose() => BusControl.Stop();
}

public class ServiceA
{
    private readonly IBus _bus;

    public ServiceA(IBusControlFactory factory) => _bus = factory.Create();

    public Task SayHi() => _bus.Publish(new TestMessage { Text = "Hi" });
}

public class ServiceB
{
    public ServiceB(IBusControlFactory factory)
    {
        factory.Create("consumer2", ep =>
        {
            ep.Handler<TestMessage>(context =>
            {
                context.Message.Text.Should().Be("Hi");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });
        });
    }
}

[Test]
public async Task Can_publish_and_receive_message_take_2()
{
    using (var harness = Harness.Start())
    {
        var serviceA = new ServiceA(harness);
        var serviceB = new ServiceB(harness);

        var spy = new Spy();
        harness.BusControl.ConnectConsumeMessageObserver(spy);

        await serviceA.SayHi();

        await spy.WaitOne(2.Seconds());
    }            
}

public class Spy : IConsumeMessageObserver<TestMessage>
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0);

    public Task PreConsume(ConsumeContext<TestMessage> context) => Task.CompletedTask;

    public Task PostConsume(ConsumeContext<TestMessage> context)
    {
        _semaphore.Release();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task ConsumeFault(ConsumeContext<TestMessage> context, Exception exception) => Task.CompletedTask;
    public async Task WaitOne(TimeSpan timeout) { (await _semaphore.WaitAsync(timeout)).Should().BeTrue(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it was refactored out.

`GetSendEndpoint` will never resolve another bus `ISendEndpoint` instance because:

```cs
var queueName = address.AbsolutePath.Split('/').Last();
```

ignores "Virtual Host" in the Uri (`loopback://localhost/VirtualHost/QueueName`)

There is one test with two bus instances `InMemoryDuo_Specs.cs` where it just passes the bus instance for communication.

**Our options are to have a lookup of bus instances / send endpoints or a single shared bus with unique queues when testing.**

Edit:
Another problem for the first solution `ConsumeContext`.`Send` inside a handler wont work either, so you have to have a dirty way to get the right instance.